# How to show a Warning message to the user (and stress the severity of the situation)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seam

I've been trying to show a warning message to the customer in a way that he'll know that it is a warning, or something that he did wrong.
But all I know how to do is a info message. How can I make it looks more severe?

```
if (this.instance.getName().trim().equals("")){
    addFacesMessage("You must type a name!");
    return null;
}
```

This looks too friendly.

Comment: You might want to edit your question with some more specifics, e.g. that you are using Seam version x.x etc

Comment: You should write `"".equals(this.instance.getName().trim())` instead to avoid nullpointerexceptions

Comment: @Shervin - can you really call the trim() method on a null string? (I'd agree with your technique for avoiding NPEs if it wasn't for the trim)

Answer (score 2):

As Shervin told you should use StatusMessages instead of FacesMessages. StatusMessages has a lot of nice methods, you can also look at them.

```
import org.jboss.seam.international.StatusMessages;
import org.jboss.seam.international.StatusMessage.Severity;
....
StatusMessages.instance().add(Severity.ERROR, "Message");
```

after that you can use errorStyle, fatalStyle, warnStyle of the  to customize look and feel of the messages.

```
<h:messages errorStyle="yourStyle" />
```

Comment: It happens the same thing as with FacesMessages. Eclipse doesn't let me do it. It says: "The method add(StatusMessage.Severity, String) is undefined for the type FacesMessage", and does not accept its suggestions. Any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: you should use org.jboss.seam.international.StatusMessage.Severity instead of StatusMessage.Severity. you can use above import statements.

Comment: I'll try it and I'll let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Use Status Messages like this

```
StatusMessages.instance().add(Severity.ERROR, "Incorrect answers below.");
```

don't use **FacesMessages** .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inject:

```
@In
FacesMessages facesMessages;
facesMessages.add(Severity.WARN, "Your message");
```

Severity is a enum containing several warning levels.

Comment: Use `StatusMessages` instead. `FacesMessages` is deprecated

Comment: Eclipse doesn't let me do it. It says: "The method add(StatusMessage.Severity, String) is undefined for the type FacesMessage", and does not accept its suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a logger?

```
logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
logger.severe(message);
```

Comment: Loggers are really for an internal record of events.The messages in this case are for output to the end user of the web application. They are the messages you see on the next page after you've created your account or after you delete a movie from your list and you want to provide some feedback to the user on that page or the page they transition to.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your imports are correct

```
import org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesMessages;
import org.jboss.seam.international.StatusMessage.Severity;
```

Then inject `facesMessages` component.

```
@In(create = true)
FacesMessages facesMessages;
```

Then you can set the error message and severity as below

```
facesMessages.add(Severity.ERROR, "You must type a name!");
```

Now display the message as below

```
<h:messages errorStyle="color:red"/>
```

For Ajax requests use `rich:messages` component.

```
<rich:messages errorClass="yourErrClass"/>
```